# ROS Server Client communication

Tags: ros, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I want to use ROS as two parts application. Server and Client. I got a robotic arm that should run on server and i could be controlled by client over network.
Is that posible? I mean is there allready a package that could be used by me?
I find something like this, called [actionlib](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib)
but i’m not sure if its the right one.

Greets Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50596/ros-server-client-communication/) by [leva87x](https://answers.ros.org/users/3756/leva87x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're trying to connect the server computer from another client computer. You can follow [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup)

First, assume that your server IP is [sIP], and client IP is [cIP]. Make sure that you can ping [sIP] from your client computer. And then type :

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=[cIP]
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://[sIP]:11311
```

in the terminal of the client computer.

Now you can try :

```
rostopic list
```

or

```
rosnode list
```

You should be able to see the nodes and topics existing on the server computer. And then you can do any operation as if in the same computer.

Actionlib is some kind of technique that is similar to service but provides more functions. It's widely used in arm navigation and controller as I know. This might not related to your original need.

---

Originally posted by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) with karma: 301 on 2012-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3